# Three.js, проблема со светом

Tags: javascript, three.js

Необходимо, чтобы PointLight была в центре Солнца, соответственно, в определенной фазе у планет была тень, как мы видим фазы Луны.

(слишком много Юпитеров из-за того, что three отображает онлайн только https картинки, их мало в инете, но это не суть, какой окрас)

light.position.set(0, 0, 0); - крутила по разным координатам, не помогло

Ссылка на доку, чтоб не искать https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/PointLight
Заранее спасибо

```
light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.4, 7000);
light.position.set(100, 0, 0);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadowMapWidth = 204;
light.shadowMapHeight = 204;
scene.add(light);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/mgnx1cpn/

Comment: Для планет используйте материалы, отличные от `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()`. Например, `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()`. `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` никак не реагирует на наличие/отсутствие источника света в сцене